# Mac book Pro to Dell E2414H monitor issue

Tags: mac, hdmi, vga

I am trying to connect my MBP with my DELL monitor. I have purchased an HDMI to VGA adapter(converter). when I connect them, my MBP flashes on and off intermittently and my external monitor says nothing is connected. I have checked and rechecked all the connections but am having no luck.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the Dell monitor has a DVI connector, try that instead of VGA. It means purchasing additional cables/adaptors, though. You should edit your question to include the model of the MBP & name/number of the Dell monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Adapters can be finicky things.  I have had mixed results even with genuine Apple display adapters.  You would think something this simple would be a no-brainier; just buy, plug in and go to work.  It may be the adapter itself that is giving you problems so you will want to return it and get another.

However, as has been previously stated, you should be using the DVI port.  The VGA is analog and while not "bad" per se, you are not getting the full performance of your monitor by using VGA and you may be introducing issues like what you are experiencing because the the DP to VGA adapter has to convert digital video signals to analog.  Then, interestingly enough, the monitor has to convert the analog signal back to digital.

Why not just go digital end-to-end?

I personally used this cable with great results  [Mini Display Port to DVI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DJCB83O).  This one is Thunderbolt compatible as well.

Why this and not an adapter and a separate DVI cable?  I prefer having a single connection end-to-end as the more connections you make means more points-of-failure.  That cable above has worked for me on several MacBooks, an iMac27 and a Surface Pro 3 tablet.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the specs for the Dell E2414H monitor, it has a DVI (digital) connector. What you need is a Mini DisplayPort-to-DVI adapter.

Unfortunately, it appears that Apple no longer sells such an adapter (they used to have it last summer).

Looking at Newegg, [here is an example](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815158182&cm_re=mini_displayport_to_dvi-_-15-158-182-_-Product) of the adapter that you need.

Answer (score 0):

First off: In principal your approach should work. Unfortunately it clearly doesn't for you. As suggest by Vzzdak. You can try a  [Mini DisplayPort-to-DVI adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB570LL/B/mini-displayport-to-dvi-adapter)